# Корректно ли использование Ember Set в Ember Octane

Tags: javascript, массивы, promise, handlebars, ember.js

В Ember Octane `this.set` заменено прямым присвоением значения в нужное поле.
Между тем осталась возможность импортировать `set` для использования с специфичными `ember object`.
В тоже время `set` корректно работает и с Glimmer компонентами.

В подавляющем количестве случаев простое присвоение работает корректно, и `@tracked` поля обновляются правильно. Но, например, в случае использования `apollo.query`, который возращает `promise` и изменении массива по индексу, изменения отображаются после разрешения промиса.

Например, в данном случае, где есть массив с индикаторами загрузки для каждого элемента перебираемого через `each`:

```
{{#each this.items as |item index|}}
  <SomeComponent @loading={{get this.loading index}}/>
{{/each}}
```

```
this.loading[index] = true;
    
this.apollo.query({ query: CurrentQuery }, 'query_name').then(() => {
    this.loading[index] = false;
})
```

Ember не отобразит индикатор загрузки, хотя в коде данные своевременно обновились.

Если убрать `this.loading[index] = false;`, то индикация отобразится после разрешения промиса, хоть и была объявлена раньше.

2 решения которые помогают решить эту промлему, это использование `set`:

```
set(this, 'loading.' + index, true);
```

Или после установки значения, перезадать поле само в себя:

```
this.loading[index] = true;
this.loading = this.loading;
```

Собственно от того возникает несколько вопросов:

1. Корректно ли использовать `Ember Set` в случаях изменения конкретного элемента массива или лучше перезадавать поле само в себя, или же есть более правильные методы.
2. Корректно ли вообще использовать `Ember Set` в проектах на Ember Octane и не планируется ли разработчиками Ember в дальнейшем удалить поддержку `set` даже в виде отдельного пакета?